# Im having an error on my command text even though the command text is right when i test it in the SQL console

Tags: c#, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source D://sqldatabase.sql' at line 1.

```
MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "source D://sqldatabase.sql";
try {
    conn.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
} catch (MySqlException a) {
    MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have tried to fix the issue.

Comment: Regardless what he would have tried, there is no way to get it fixed like that

Answer (score 2):

"source" is a command for the mysql command-line tool and is not recognized by the server at all.

So when using mysql.exe (the command line client), it knows what to do with it, the mysql-server doesn't.

And C# doesn't know either. You will have to read the file into your program, and execute the commands therein one by one manually.

Another way as said in the comments would be to run mysql.exe from the program:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

Process mysql = new Process( );

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "Path\\To\\mysql.exe";
psi.Arguments = " -u[username] -p[password] [database] < D:\\sqldatabase.sql";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;

P.StartInfo = psi;
P.Start();
```

Be aware that:

1. Using a password on the command line may be insecure
2. There is no whitespace between -p and the password (important!)

Comment: Well technically you could run the `mysql.exe` command with some C# code.

Comment: Correct, didn't think about that.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much